# How to connect this standard switch

Tags: wiring, switch, dimmer-switch

I have a dimmer switch that I am replacing with a standard switch. The original dimmer only has two black wires coming out of it (pre-1996) and inside the box were two black wires tied to one of the black wires from the dimmer and a pink one tied to the other black wire from the dimmer. The white ones and the copper wire (Which I thought was ground) were not connected to anything. I connected the copper to the ground (?) and the pink to the top. The two black wires would not fit in the bottom screw and everything that is on that breaker will not work unless those two are connected as shown in the picture. Do I need a special switch to connect this?
[image: wall switch box]

Comment: Dimmer had a **black wire**, while the new switch just has a screw. So you need a **black wire**, a.k.a., a pigtail - connect that to the switch screw and the other two black wires with a wire nut and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You add a short piece of black wire to the two blacks.

Instead of just two wires under the wire nut, there will be three.  This is usually called a pigtail.

The connection to the switch is with the two single wires.

The white wires are your neutral and are connected correctly.

The ground(bare) wire should be connected to the box with a screw and maybe to the switch, but not always needed. The switch should make ground connection by the screws attaching it to the box.

Answer (score 0):

Wire nut a third wire to the group of black wires and attach that to the switch. This should be your power source ("line"). The red (pink) wire will provide power to your device/light ("load") when the switch is on.

Does your new switch have a silver screw for a neutral wire? If so, you'll want a pigtail from the white wires as well attached that that.